# Powershell - invoke sharepoint ribbon command in internetexplorer.application comobject

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, sharepoint, com, ribbon

I have a powershell script that needs to access a sharepoint document library as a UNC path - up until now it's proven impossible to script that reliably as the only way the UNC path works is once it's been accessed directly through windows explorer - it invokes the necessary WebDAV behind the scenes which seems to cache the path somewhere so it now works via `test-path`, `copy-item` etc (I've tried to emulate that using `System.Net.WebClient` and `Invoke-WebRequest` but they don't seem to do what Windows Explorer is doing).

So, does anyone know how to have a powershell script invoke that command that runs when you click on `Library > Open With Explorer` on the sharepoint ribbon?

I have the following code that opens the SP doc library in PS:

```
$oIE=new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$oIE.navigate2("http://uk.sharepoint.mydomain.local/sites/mycompany/myteam/Shared Documents/Reports")
while ($oIE.busy) {
    sleep -milliseconds 50
}
$oIE.visible=$true
```

And in the page source I see the following relating to Open With Explorer:

```
{'Command':'OpenWithExplorer','ClickScript':'CoreInvoke\\u0028\\u0027NavigateHttpFolder\\u0027,\\u0027http:\\\\u002f\\\\u002fuk.sharepoint.mydomain.local\\\\u002fsites\\\\u002fmycompany\\\\u002fmyteam\\\\u002fShared Documents\\u0027, \\u0027_blank\\u0027\\u0029;','HiddenScript':'!\\u0028SupportsNavigateHttpFolder\\u0028\\u0029\\u0029','LabelText':'Open with Windows Explorer','Description':'Drag and drop files into this library.'}
```

Comment: would it possible to use CSOM + PowerShell to access the library?
or maybe this script is helpful to you:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/OneDriveMapper-automaticall-d7d498b0

Comment: @Shawn CSOM looks interesting, will do some experimenting with that!